# jquery: $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I run a wordpress blog.
It includes Jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0'></script>
```

When I run `jQuery`
I got:

```
function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

when I try

```
$("div")
```

I got

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)

when I try `jQuery("div")`

I got:

> a.fn.init[203]

How can I use Jquery ?

Comment: somewhere else in your page, you have `jQuery.noConflict()`, looks like you are using wordpress, I think wordpress does that

Comment: instead of `$`, you can use `jQuery` to refer to jquery library

Comment: i think you missed ' after src in second script

Comment: As @el-oz said there is a problem, `jquery-migrate.min.js` is not loaded… **Questions:** How do you use query? Directly in the php code between `<script>` html tags? Or in a js file enqueued? … Running `$("div")` alone is not useful, so what action or event are you using with? … You need also to use the jQuery "ready" trick before using your jQuery code, to ensure all DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

`$` is an alias of the `jQuery()` function, which apparently missing in this case...

One way is to do, between jQuery and your other scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery;
</script>
```

It should work

Comment: $("div") return exactly what jQuery("div"): a.fn.init[203]: it returns a function, not DOM

Comment: It might be a jQuery object, not DOM one... did you try to call jquery method, after?

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you, this is due to [`jQuery.noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). You can use a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to map the `$` variable to `jQuery` and simply place your logic inside of the expression:

```
(function($) {
    // $ is now the same as jQuery

    $('body').remove();
})(jQuery);
// ^^^^^^ we're passing this to the "function($)" call
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery is not bound to the `$` variable (to avoid conflicts, probably).

If you want to use the `$` variable then you can create a scope wherein it will be bound to that variable:

```
(function ($) {
    // Use $ in this scope
}(jQuery));
```

If all your code should run when the document is ready (which is usually how it is done) then you can also use the scope that jQuery creates for you:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Document ready, use $ in this scope...
});
```

You can also just add jQuery to a global `$` variable. If you know for certain that only jQuery will be using that variable then it is probably fine.

```
$ = jQuery;
```